# How to Query Data in Firebase by Specific Child Value?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm starting with firebase and I have a problem with data query. I have this firebase database:

```
  "Conversations" : {

    "-L9LJQiFKqGlNKKFEyvd" : {

      "-L9LJQiHrp1rU1pblNG_" : {
        "messageText" : "Hi there",
        "postTime" : 1522940321427,
        "senderId" : "GSJMlFA3pYMjYCfY6BA0AEyva9u2",
        "senderNickname" : "q"
      },
      "-L9LZ0O2rXHe-eh2iRgB" : {
        "messageText" : "f",
        "postTime" : 1522944447238,
        "senderId" : "GSJMlFA3pYMjYCfY6BA0AEyva9u2",
        "senderNickname" : "q"
      },
      "-L9LZ7uF9TPb4VZ-wJEO" : {
        "messageText" : "vvvv",
        "postTime" : 1522944478035,
        "senderId" : "GSJMlFA3pYMjYCfY6BA0AEyva9u2",
        "senderNickname" : "q"
      }
    }
  },
```

I would like to show get reference to those push() object which "postTime" value is higher than some specific value like for example: 1522944447230.
I've tried with:

```
mConversationId = "-L9LJQiFKqGlNKKFEyvd"
mLeaveTime = 1522944447230;

mUserConversationsReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Conversations");

mUserConversationsMessagesReference = mUserConversationsReference.child(mConversationId);

mLastMessageQuery  = mUserConversationsMessagesReference.orderByChild("postTime").orderByValue().startAt(mLeaveTime);
```

but then I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You can't combine multiple orderBy
>   calls!

So there must be probably another way to solve this issue. I would be grateful for any advice.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the floowing lines of code:

```
String mConversationId = "-L9LJQiFKqGlNKKFEyvd"
long mLeaveTime = 1522944447230;
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mConversationIdRef = rootRef.child("Conversations").child(mConversationId);
Query query = mConversationIdRef.orderByChild("postTime").startAt(mLeaveTime);
```

`.orderByValue()` has nothing to do you in this query. And note, Firebase does not allow you to use multiple orderBy calls. So to solve this, ony one is enough.